# Overriding abstract methods when using generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have the following classes:

Base class

```
public abstract class ArrayManipulation {

    public <T> T[] largestSubArray(T[] a){
        (((CharacterArrayManipulation)this).compare(a[0],a[1]); 
         return a;
     }

    abstract <T> boolean compare(T a,T b);
}
```

Sub class

```
public class CharacterArrayManipulation extends ArrayManipulation<Character> {

    public Character[] largestSubArray(Character[] input){

        super.largestSubArray(input)); 
    }

   //This is not seen as overriding
protected boolean compare(Character a, Character b){
        return a==b;
    }
}
```

I want to override the `compare` function in the sub-class `CharacterArrayManipulation`. When I try  to do that, I get 
`CharacterArrayManipulation must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method compare(T,T) in ArrayManipulation`

## EDIT

I changed it to the following after the comments, it still seems to give the same error:

Base class

```
public abstract class ArrayManipulation<T> {

    public T[] largestSubArray(T[] a){
    this.compare(a[0],a[1]); 
         return a;
     }

    abstract boolean compare(T a,T b);
}
```

Sub class

```
public class CharacterArrayManipulation extends ArrayManipulation<Character> {

    public Character[] largestSubArray(Character[] input){

        super.largestSubArray(input)); 
    }

   //This is not seen as overriding
@Override
boolean compare(Character a, Character b){
        return a==b;
    }
}
```

Comment: A class should not know of its sub-classes.

Comment: Your code cannot compile. `ArrayManipulation` isn't a generic class, so you can't use `ArrayManipulation<Character>`.

Comment: ...and you have extra parentheses in a couple of places.

Comment: Is your code still as it is in your edit? If so, remove the angled brackets from `<T>` in the method declaration in `ArrayManipulation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your super class should not have any knowledge of its sub classes, and so the implementation of `ArrayManipulation.largestSubArray()` should be left empty and abstract, or non-empty with a body that does not do any casting to sub classes (the casting is unnecessary as all sub classes of `ArrayManipulation` will have an overridden version of `compare()`, not just `CharacterArrayManipulation`).

Your super class isn't generic, as you haven't added the `T` generic to the class header.

```
public abstract class ArrayManipulation<T> { ... }
```

You should then remove the generic declaration from the `largestSubArray()` method and the `compare()` method.

```
public T[] largestSubArray(T[] a){ ... }
boolean compare(T a, T b);
```

You can't use an access modifier in the overriding version that is different to the overridden version.

```
// Note the lack of `protected`
boolean compare(Character a, Character b){ ... }
```

**Side-note**: You should use the `@Override` annotation when overriding methods. It will give you more applicable error messages and explicitly says that you are attempting to override a method.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, it still seems to have the same error, please check the comment.

Comment: The compare() method is still generic, and shouldn't be. It should be declared as `abstract boolean compare(T a,T b);`, not as `abstract <T> boolean compare(T a,T b);`. Otherwise, it's not the same T.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a method with a generic placeholder you get a generic method. Even when you use the same name for the placeholder as in the surrounding class this is not the same.

The problem is:

```
abstract <T> boolean compare(T a,T b);
```

This `T` is different (try, it will give the same error when renamed to `U`).

When understanding your code right, simply removing the declaration of this additional generic variable will solve your problem:

```
abstract boolean compare(T a,T b);
```

now the generic placeholder of the class is used which is what you expected I think.